# Find actual viewport height - minus the chrome

Tags: javascript

HI,

Can anyone tell me how to get the actual viewport height? If i use  window.innerHeight or $(window).height() (jquery) I get back a value that looks like it's taking the browser chrome in to account. I need the height of the actual viewport. When I measure the viewport height using a ruler plugin in the web dev toolbar (firefox) the value is different than what the window.innerHeight provides me with.

Comment: Can you show an example? Which browsers does this happen in?

Comment: `window.innerHeight` doesn't take the browser chrome into account, that's what `window.outerHeight` does.  It does include the horizontal scrollbar, if present.

Comment: $(window).height() in jquery only returns the viewport height, not browser height.

Comment: Oh ok, It's just that when I alert out window.innerHeight i get 760. but if i measure the actual area from a screengrab or using the ruler function in firefox plugin then i get back 726.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.body.clientHeight
document.body.clientWidth
```

Comment: That gets the height of the document, not the window - i.e. if the window has scrollbars it will get the full length of the page, including the parts off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```